# In wix editor , How in html code to calculate target given date time according to my own current date time? getting error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this widget countdown with html code:

This code is working but I want to add some new feature that give me error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        /* Disable pointer events for the countdown timer */
        .countdown-timer {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Countdown Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.logwork.com/widget/countdown.js"></script>
    <a href="https://logwork.com/countdown-831z" class="countdown-timer" data-timezone="Asia/Jerusalem" data-date="2023-12-05 16:00">Countdown Tester</a>
</body>
</html>
```

the target future time to count to is "2023-12-05 16:00"

what I want to do now is that anyone who will browse the site to calculate automatically and convert the target time according to the user local date time.

so for me it will count down to "2023-12-05 16:00" but if someone in the usa will browse to this site and his time is et or pm, or am or pacific or any time then to automatically adjust the target date time counting to.

so each one that will browse to the site will a different count down target time.  the init count time target will be the same for everyone but it will convert it and change the target time depending on the user local time.

so everyone target time will be "2023-12-05 16:00" but display the count time to that target depending on the user local time.

I tried this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        /* Disable pointer events for the countdown timer */
        .countdown-timer {
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Countdown Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.logwork.com/widget/countdown.js"></script>
    <a href="https://logwork.com/countdown-831z" class="countdown-timer" data-timezone="auto" data-date="2023-12-05 16:00">Countdown Tester</a>

    <script>
        // Get the user's local time zone offset in minutes
        var userTimeZoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();

        // Convert the target date to the user's local time
        var targetDate = new Date("2023-12-05T16:00:00");
        targetDate.setMinutes(targetDate.getMinutes() + userTimeZoneOffset);

        // Format the target date and time as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
        var formattedTargetDate = targetDate.toISOString().slice(0, 16).replace("T", " ");

        // Update the data-date attribute with the adjusted target date and time
        document.querySelector('.countdown-timer').setAttribute('data-date', formattedTargetDate);

        // Initialize the countdown timer with the adjusted target date
        logwork_countdown();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but then this give me error: incorrect embedded code please , regenerate your countdown widget code